# Выбор языка программирования для простых программ под windows

Tags: windows

В данный момент знаю скриптовый язык программирования PHP на среднем уровне.
 Сейчас появилась потребность в изучении языка на котором можно было бы писать простые программы которые работали бы под windows и linux.
 В данном вопросе пока полный чайник, возможно говорю глупость, если не правильно подправьте.

Одна из задач которую мне бы хотелось реализовать, это создание программы типа онлайн консультанта.  1 человек пишет с сайта php+ajax+html, второй получает сообщение и отвечает на него в самой программе.

Какой язык выбрать?

Comment: если знаете php - используйте его. Саму программу для начала можете написать также в браузере - вполне себе кроссплатформенно. Позже, просто перейдете на использование xmpp и проблем с декстопной частью не будет.

Comment: Ну если очень хочеться, то лучший выбор будет ИМХО Java (исходя из простоты и кроссплатформенности)

Comment: @MDJHD .NET тоже вполне кроссплатформенно. Более того, оно не уступает джаве: [Сравнительное тестирование производительности платформ .Net, Java и Mono](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120090/)

Comment: Или python. Хотя не знаю как там с кроссплатформенным GUI.

Но если нужно просто решить задачу, а не расширить свои познания в ЯПах, то лучше просто отправлять сообщения в xmpp (например из php бекэнда) или вообще сделать всё в вебе знакомыми инструментами.

Хотя в целом учить новые ЯП полезно для саморазвития.

Comment: из старого:

    У москалии москаль дуже любит свий паскаль.
    Мы ж в Украине уси программуему на Си

    Мне ассемблер всех милей -- я, по вашему -- еврей

    Лучше фокса нет язык -- буду друг степей калмык

Comment: alexlz, ну и к чему это ты мелкую простыню написал?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вам нужен бэкэнд для клиента. Почему бы в вашем случае не попробовать Node.js

Answer (score -2):

Java очень ресурсоёмкая. IDE Eclipse в связке с ADT, написанная на Java, кушает 500 МБ ОЗУ.
Mono/GTK# шустрее, но сыроват.

Выбирайте нативные инструменты.

Comment: все IDE много жрут

Comment: Много - понятие растяжимое.
Более прожорливых, чем Eclipse и Netbeans, я не видел.

Comment: Причем здесь ADT

Comment: @Водяной Змей, у меня на ноутбуке phpstorm ест 450 (та же java), но какое это вообще имеет отношение? Какое отношение имеет "много - понятие растяжимое"? Какая разница (в контексте вопроса), какая IDE более прожорлива? Все IDE без исключения имеют последним приоритетом экономию ресурсов, первым - глубину разбора кода и количество плюшек для разработки.  
Если уж агрессивно сравнивать java и c#, то надо считать ресурсы, необходимые для запуска VM.

Comment: Просто ADT подразумевает запуск эмулятора параллельно IDE, который сам кушает 512 МБ ОЗУ, или надо 10 минут ждать его загрузки.
А так, Eclipse и без ADT кушает не меньше.

Visual Studio во всех видах и разновидностях, PureBasic, С++ Builder, Delphi куда менее прожорливы, чем Eclipse.
Хотя глубина разбора кода у Visual Studio точно не намного хуже Eclipse'овского.
Ну поддерживается в Eclipse список самых типовых ошибок, типа import лишний или наоборот отсутствует, и что, на это лишних 200-300 МБ нужно?


Java с C# не сравниваю, скорее сравниваю их оба с нативными инструментами.

Comment: @Водяной Змей, мы все понимаем боль по поводу IDE, на которые было потрачено много сил, но это не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу. *Да и оперативка стоит копейки*

Уместным были бы рассуждения, например, про копии переменных в условиях многопоточности и подобные тонкости, но даже они, думаю, автору мало что подскажут на этом этапе.

Comment: Проблема не в IDE.
IDE - лишь пример, на котором я показал особо высокую ресурсоёмкость Java по сравнению с иными платформами.
Раз IDE, написанные на Java, кушают в 3-5 раз больше ресурсов, чем остальные, то и иные программы, написанные на Java, тоже будут кушать больше.
Если бы мне кто-то сказал "Я знаю только джаву, и программу, которую Вы хотите, могу написать только на ней, так что будьте добры купить дополнительную  планку ОЗУ за столько-то к", я не стал бы с этим человеком сотрудничать.